# How to add a class to a label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've seen some similar questions, but couldn't find the right solution for me. I have a textfield:

```
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset ui-input-type-text">
         <input type="text" name="FreiFeld3" data-model-binding="FreiFeld3" class="fw-model-binding" 
         data-set-visibility-id="id_15_gen" id="id_16_gen" data-framework-widget-name="textinput" maxlength="300"></div>
```

with an associated label:

```
    <label for="id_16_gen">Name</label>
```

Now I simply need to add a class to this label with javascript or jquery, so it looks like this:

```
    <label for="id_16_gen" class="app-required-label">Name</label>
```

I've tried various things with toggle class and so on but nothing worked. Everytime the class got added to the input tag with the same id, but not to the label.

For Explanation: I have some Checkboxes and when some are checked, this textfield with label appears. When it appears I need to add the class to change its optic, because it needs to be a required field then. (After the label change, I'm going to add required attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class to label like this :

```js
$("label[for='id_16_gen']").addClass("app-required-label");
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you very much.